# Java Web Start in 10.8.2 with native (Apple) Java 1.6 can't find JRE

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, java, java-web-start

I'm trying to run a some .jnlp applications (games) on latest os-x. While doing so Java Web Start.app propose me to install Java Runtime Environment (jre_7u9). Should not that be already included in os-x, java 1.6? As an example I use Eclipse which is java-based and I have no problems running it. I'm just worried that the  new version could mess up something what works fine so far (saw couple of threads where people experience problems after installation of java 7, even with the Mail application!).

I know close to nothing about java, so if someone could point me to the solution which does not involve installation of jre_7u9, it would be nice.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Denis.

EDIT1:

It seems that user/bin/javaws points to the wrong direction:

```
javaws
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
```

that is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws
```

If i change it to (as suggested here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws
```

it does work fine, however it does not help Java Web Start.app to run properly, it still requires JRE installation, which is a nonsense.

p/s/ [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004854/is-there-any-way-to-reenable-javaws-with-java-6-on-osx-lion/13012740#13012740) thread discuss the same problem. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71428/mountain-lion-with-java-6-2012-006-web-plugin-javaws-cant-find-jre) one as well. But so far i don't see any solution to make Java Web Start to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A detailed guide on how to solve this problem is presented in [Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559).

Comment: i don't think this is my issue. I don't have jre7 installed yet

Comment: I am answering your question with the thinking that you want to run the version of JRE that came bundled with the OS.

Comment: i still think it's not proper. For example, consider step 5 in that tutorial. I already have javaws in /usr/bin/javaws. It is when I execute it it asks for JRE. The link you gave looks rather like a switch to the old version

Comment: p/s/ please, consider my Edit1 to see why it does not solve the problem.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, even though I did not have jre7 installed yet. My version is and was: java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)

Comment: I experienced this issue with OSX Mavericks. Following this solution got me up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem where I could run javaws from the command line, but running from Chrome/Safari/Finder did not work using Java Web Start.  The problem I found is that Java Web Start is looking for a user preference that does not exist.  I was able to get this working by running:

```
defaults write com.apple.java.JavaPreferences WebComponentsEnabled -bool true
```